# Unable to solve this metric space question

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've asked this question before on stackexchange for any hints or suggestions. However, there weren't sufficient replies and  I was not able to solve this question. So now I'm looking for a solution.

Let $A$ be a subset of the set of all non negative real numbers. It is required to show the existence of a metric space $X$, such that the set of all non-zero distances of $X$ equal the set $A$. All solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "'I've asked this question before on stackexchange for any hints or suggestions. However, there weren't sufficient replies and I was not able to solve this question. "... maybe you should take a hint.

Comment: Since you're new: the proper way to deal with a question that hasn't had responses is to edit it to clarify / expand it (which bumps the post), or offer a bounty to raise attention. Also, please give more than a day for a response.

Comment: A = {0} is a counter example.

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\{0\} \not \subset \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: @fleablood.  Even though 0 is not a positive number 0 is a non-negative number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X = \{0\} \cup A$ and define $d:X^2 \to X$ by
$$
d(a,b) = 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } a=b,\\
\max\{a,b\} &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
This defines a distance because:

- $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ follows from, if $x \neq y$, then suppose wlog $x < y$, and it follows that $\max\{x,y\}=y \neq 0$.
- If $x=y$, then $d(x,y)=0=d(y,x)$; if $x < y$, then $d(x,y)=y=d(y,x)$.
- $d(x,z) = \max\{x,z\} \leq \max\{x,y\}+\max\{y,z\}$, because each of $x$ and $z$ is less than $\max\{x,y\}+\max\{y,z\}$; so $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$.

It is clear that for $a \in A$, we have $d(0,a)=a$, so $A \subseteq d(X^2)$.
If $a,b \in X$ are such that $a \neq b$, say, $a < b$, then $d(a,b) = b \in A$ because if $a < b$ then $b \neq 0$; so $d(X^2) \setminus \{0\} \subseteq A$.
Hence $A = d(X^2) \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: What if $\max (a,b) \not \in A$?

Comment: @fleablood that can only happen if $a=b=0$, since $X = \{0\}\cup A$. Am I missing something?

Comment: no, you are not missing anything.  *I* was missing something in that I didn't get that we can choose $X$ and .... I don't know what I was thinking.  I racked my brain but for some reason I had convinced myself that X couldn't be specific and we had to account for all possible X.  ... You are absolutely right and I was absolutely wrong.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, I was trying now to tell you that. By the way, do you confirm the example is right?

Comment: Oh, yes.  Your answer is perfect.   I had considered it and the like but for some brain-farty lapse of sensibility I thought had to allow for all possible $X$ up to and including the entirety of $\mathbb R^+$... which I don't think would be possible.

Comment: @fleablood Yes I suppose it's like we misread a logical formula swapping the quantifiers. It happens. Thank you for checking it!

Comment: I will nitpick that $X$ need not include $0$.  ... nitpick..:)  (Speaking of swapping quantifiers.  $d(x,y)$ must be in A, not X, and only if x \ne y.  So there is no need to include $0$ in X.  ... There's no harm in include $0$ in X... but there's no need.

Comment: @fleablood After changing the answer I realised that we actually need $0$, for suppose $A$ has a minimum, $a_0$. Then, $d(a_0,a_0)=0$ and for all other $x, y \in A$ we have $d(x,y) = \max\{x,y\} > a_0$. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, but the question was only about a set of non-zero real numbers and non-zero distances.